# Create local ".git" repository programmatically

Tags: git, .git-folder

**Problem:** I have root folder with subfolders / files and I need to create git repository inside this root folder programmatically (without using git tool). The general structure should be simple - new repo and only 1 commit with all files.

I've tried to find specification for `.git` folder but haven't found good explanation how to encode and generate `objects` folder and `index` file inside the `.git` folder. Could you please guide me how to do that?

**Complication:** If I solve this problem there is 1 additional complication - some files could be changed. E.g. I have the original file data in memory and I need to use this data + file path.

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you read the [relevant folder structure docs page](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrepository-layout) and [object storage format](https://git-scm.com/docs/user-manual#object-details) from the Git Book? Also, can you clarify your constraints: Why are you trying to make a `git`-compatible folder without using `git`, and is there no possibility of invoking "`git` plumbing" commands that would let you defer that complexity to invocations of [git-fast-import](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fast-import) or at least [git-hash-object](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-hash-object)?

Comment: Are you trying to implement git yourself? Or is using the git library sufficient?

Comment: You could hire a really strong person to lift your car while you change a tire, or you can use a tire jack. Why can't you use the tire jack in this case ("the git tool")?

Comment: Welcome to SO! There's a talk [Git From the Bits Up](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MYP56QJpDr4) that can give you a short overview of what's inside the `.git` folder, what the files mean, and a little bit on indexing. But if you want to programmatically interact with `git`, something like [`libgit2`](https://libgit2.org/) or a 3rd party language binding might be closer to what you want rather than reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 4):

You *can* do this by hand by examining the contents and format of a normal repository and reading the Pro Git book linked on the website, but I would strongly recommend against doing that.  Git repositories are reasonably complex, and you would be better off either using the `git` binary or a binding of libgit2 (which has bindings for several languages).

Doing it yourself runs the risk of creating corrupt objects, and if you do that your repositories generally will not be able to be pushed anywhere, since most hosting providers reject malformed data.  You will also run the risk of data loss.

libgit2 is a good approach if you don't want to use Git, but do note that it lacks some features (like SHA-256 repository support) compared to the Git binary.

Answer (score 0):

I definitely would suggest just using `git init && git add -m "Initial commit" .` but if you insist not using the `git` binary but have e.g. `python` version 3, you can follow instructions at https://wyag.thb.lt/

Basically you create whole git repository (`.git` directory) using home made code to create commits, tree objects and blob objects plus a few metadata files. Your home made repository will end up being bigger than what git would do automatically but it will work with the official git binary.

If you don't have python either, you should include *full list of limitations* in the question.